# Google Maps iOS SDK crash in background

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-geocoding-api

I 've an iOs today extension that should get the user location address so i 've implemented the Google Maps SDK for iOS.
The problem is that my today extension crash with the message :
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'GMSBackgroundAppException', reason: 'Background execution would crash in this scenario'

this is the code (in view did load)

```
    [[GMSServices  sharedServices ] provideAPIKey:@"MyApiKey"];
    GMSGeocoder *geocoder = [GMSGeocoder geocoder];
```

Are there a way to allow background execution of GMSGeocoder in background?

Comment: You should do the `[[GMSServices  sharedServices ] provideAPIKey:@"MyApiKey"];' in your AppDelegate.m file's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.